# How to ignore the escape sequence warning in awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I using the below command to get the line number for the specific string

```
str_to_search="\/searchString >"
fileName=Myfile.txt
startingCt=$(awk '$0 ~ str{print NR; exit }' str="$str_to_search" $fileName)
endingCt=$(($startingCt + 3))
echo $startingCt
echo $endingCt
```

I am able to get the line numbers but i am getting the warning message for escape sequence as

> awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain`/'

Please let me know if there is any way to ignore the warnings for escape sequence and is there any better way of getting the line number. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably related to your awk version.

See the link here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474549

Here is way with AWK:

```
gawk '/PATTERN/ {print FNR}' filename
```

May I also offer this solution, although it's not using awk?

```
sed -n '/pattern/=' filename
```

Sed and AWK kind of like cute brothers, you will find some kind of version of them on many systems, and the share a lot of features, but with different ways of using them.

The above command will output only the line number of the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: i do not have control over awk version here. Is there any other way i can get the first match line number. i used grep -n but it prints all the matching line number.

Comment: probably, but share with us which awk you do have installed

Comment: @ Oz123 GNU Awk 3.1.5